# Google Tasks as a standalone window (or app)

Tags: google-chrome, google-tasks

I'd like to use Google Tasks, not from the sidebar of Gmail or Google Calendar, etc., but as a standalone browser window.

Even better would be to open it as a Chrome / Firefox webapp (i.e. a standalone non-browser window).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to get it working straight from a PWA shurtcut:

1. Go to the workaround URL:
   [https://tasks.google.com/embed/list/~default?origin=https://mail.google.com](https://tasks.google.com/embed/list/%7Edefault?origin=https://mail.google.com)
   (this one should not redirect, but if google changes stuff again,
   just take the working URL and append the
   ?origin=https://mail.google.com parameter)
2. Ctrl+Shift+C to open DevTools, go to Go to Sources > Overrides > Select folder and set up a local override folder. Allow DevTools
   full access to that folder and make sure the Enable Local Override
   checkbox is checked.
3. Go to sources > page and find the manifest.json file (it's currently on  tasks.google.com > _ > TasksWebEmbedUi > manifest.json
   )
4. Right click the file and click "Save for Overrides"
5. Find the start_url variable and change it's value to the workaround URL.
6. Save, reload, and install. Should work, you're welcomed :D

No third party extensions or anything, just a small edit to the manifest (spent like 3 hours stubbornly working on it lol)

Answer (score 1):

Simple steps:

1. Open Gmail or Google Calendar - Calendar is less code, so easier
2. Open the tasks sidebar panel
3. Right-click on the tasks panel and click "inspect"
4. In the new sidepanel with the source, scroll up a bit from the highlighted  until you see
5. copy the iframe element (right-click, copy, copy element)
6. paste into a plaintext editor (TextEdit, Gedit, NotePad, etc.)
7. take the entire URL in " that starts with `https://tasks.google.com` and ends with `__features__`

paste it into the browser (where you are logged into your Google account).

Bookmark it.

You can turn this into a Chrome webapp, but the tasks will not load when starting the Chrome webapp directly. However, you can always open the bookmark, and then from the address bar use `open in` to open it in the Chrome webapp that you created.

Answer (score 1):

GO TO THE PINNED APP ON TASKBAR AND CHANGE IT TO READ THE FOLLOWING, EXCEPT REPLACE YOUR "APP-ID" WITH THE ONE INSTALLED ON YOUR PC--->

"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome_proxy.exe" --profile-directory=Default -app-id=hobmlbmihfdboanobochnbnepoociknf --app-launch-url-for-shortcuts-menu-item=https://tasks.google.com/embed/?origin=https://mail.google.com&fullWidth=1&lfhs=2